# URL.py includes no longer works together, only one or the other

Tags: python, django, django-urls

My base urls.py in the root folder is laid out as such:

```
 from django.contrib import admin 
 from django.urls import path, re_path, include

 urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('apps.main.urls')),
    path('', include('apps.login_app.urls')), ]
```

But this is only seeing the apps.main.urls urls.py in its own app.
It will not see the apps.login_app.urls.

Though when commenting out apps.main.urls, the apps.login_app.urls start working.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a prefix like

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('main/', include('apps.main.urls')),
   path('logins', include('apps.login_app.urls')), ]
```

Comment: Does this need to be done? I would like a path that is just for example localhost:8000/

Comment: The Django router won’t know where to go, or merge all urls in one file